# Blog search box results are from serverfault instead of superuser

Tags: bug, status-completed, superuser-blog

When you use the search box on the superuser blog, the Google results are from the serverfault blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had copied the theme over from the Server Fault blog and didn't change the code for the custom search engine.

We have now though! (: